# Check if elements are in a array and increment

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm having some issues with my algorythm and can't find a way through. I'm kinda rusty programming, sorry if it's a dumb question.

Let's assume I have an array like the one below

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'weight' => 2135,
        'n2' => 'John',
        'n1' => 'Jones',
    ),
    array(
        'weight' => 3245,
        'n2' => 'Sally',
        'n1' => 'Smith',
    ),
    array(
        'weight' => 5342,
        'n2' => 'Sally',
        'n1' => 'Jones',
    ),
    array(
        'weight' => 5623,
        'n2' => 'Peter',
        'n1' => 'Doe',
    )
);
```

I wanna check if two variable exist in the array, for example. I'd like to check if "**Sally**" **AND** "**Jones**" are present in one ocurrence, it doesnt matter if its in n1 or n2, what matters is that both of them are there. If they exist I wanna ++ the weight.

Else, if I search for, for example, "**John**" **AND** "**Smith**" and they are not present in the array, I'd like to push this ocurrence to the array and add a weight value to this ocurrence.

Does anyone have any idea of how I could do it? I'm blocked and working on this for like 2 days already.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the records, and check for the names

```
   foreach($records as $record){
        if (in_array("Sally", $record)) {
        //increase weight
        }else{
        //push to array
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesnt really work, because only at the end of the foreach ill know if it exists or not. But if I add a flag, itll work like a charm! :)

Comment: @diegodacal im giving you pointers as you have not showed your code. Of course you need to tweak this to your needs :)

Answer (score 0):

Completeley untested and might not do exactly what you want but this will set you on the right path.

```
$contains = FALSE;
$contains = findNames($array, $firstName, $lastName);

if($contains === TRUE)
{
    // Add your weight to the array here
} else {
    // Do something else or nothing 
}

function findNames($array, $firstName, $lastName) {
foreach($array as $arrayValues=> $arrayValue) {
    if($arrayValue['n1'] == $firstName || $arrayValue['n1'] == $lastName ||                                     $arrayValue['n2'] == $firstName || $arrayValue['n2'] == $lastName) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

OR:

```
function findNames($array, $firstName, $lastName) {

if(in_array($firstName, $array) || in_array($lastName, $array))
{
    return TRUE;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```